# Rails query for join table with not equal to data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatable

I have the following query with join table that works great:

```
@eventsmy = Event.find( 
:all, 
:joins => :rsvps, :conditions => {:rsvps => { :user_id => current_user.id }})
```

And I would also like to have another query that does the exact opposite. i.e., find all events row that are not rsvped by the current_user. I'm getting an error for the following:

```
@eventsother = Event.find(
:all, 
:joins => :rsvps, :conditions => {:rsvps => :conditions => {["user_id != ?", current_user.id]} })
```

This also gives error:

```
@eventsother = Event.find(
:all, 
:joins => :rsvps, :conditions => {:rsvps => :conditions => current_user.id! }})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that all this is doing is finding all events that OTHER users have RSVP'd to so I don't think you are approaching this the right way...

This is what you are asking for:

```
@eventsmy = Event.joins(:rsvp).where('rsvps.user_id != ?', current_user.id)
```

I think what you really need is...  If you want to find events that the current user has been invited to but has not RSVP'd to, then you'd need to do something like:

```
# RSVP Table:
:id => primary_key
:event_id => integer
:user_id => integer
:rsvp => boolean
```

And then you could do:

```
@eventsmy = Event.joins(:rsvp).where('rsvps.user_id = ? AND rsvps.rsvp = ?', current_user.id, false)
```

Which would find all events for the current user that the current user has not RSVP'd to (since RSVP is `false`).

Comment: You caught my logic error in the query! Thanks :) I should be able to solve it using your second method.